# Getting the position of the tile map in relation to the rest of the game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

FYI On about in Unity in 2D

The tile map (which is under the grid) has a different position then other game object I create.
No matter where I create the tile maps object, they have a position of (0,0,0).
However I want to get the position of the tile map object in relation to the centre of the world.
the following is screenshots of the objects:

The boxes on the top right is the rest of the objects and the centre of the world.

[image]

[image]

I've tried stuff I've found on the internet but really understood it and it hasn't worked so if you could explain your solutions too that would be a great help.

Comment: Usually (0,0) is seen as the centre of the world. What do you mean by the world centre? Do you have GameObject you treat as the centre of the world, or is the tilemap's (0,0) position not consistent with other GameObjects at (0,0)?

Comment: @TollGnoll (0,0) of the tile map when I do is not the(0,0) of the world. So when I do transform.position of the tile map it isn’t accurate.